# What does ?= mean in ABAP

Tags: abap

Can someone explain what does a question mark before an equal symbol mean?

`lo_obj ?= <lo_kernel>.`

Comment: That's simply the assignment operator for [down-casting](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abendown_cast_glosry.htm) object or data references. `less_general ?= more_general.` See [Downcasting at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) for more information.

Comment: Alritght thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`?=` is used for explicit downcast. Although it is not required for character type but recommended to use for other data type to avoid any unexpected short dump.

The best way is to check if the data element has any Routine(i.e Conversion Exit).

Answer (score 4):

`?=` is the [casting operator](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abendown_cast_glosry.htm), a shorter synonym for [`CAST`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abendown_cast_glosry.htm).